# Version Control without access to Git or any SC tools?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm in a situation where I have an **intranet** server with a Remote Desktop Access enabled. There is no access to the internet.

I don't have privileges to install Git or anything else.

I can however, transfer files to the server and do my work via ANOTHER computer that has limited access to e-mail!

My problem lies on the version-control aspect. When I commit my changes to my private repo on GitHub, I copy the files over to the server manually.

This is a high-risk because I might forget or miss replacing files.

So, as of now, I usually copy ALL the project files and replace *everything*. Also, this very act is high-risk.

What are my options in my situation?

**My current flow:**

1. In my work-laptop, I commit to the Git repo.
2. I zip the specific commit `git archive -o ../f7bbbb.zip target-commit` or bundle `git archive -o ../latest.zip target-commit $(git diff --name-only earlier-commit target-commit)`
3. I e-mail the .zip file to computer@limited-access.dev
4. On the computer@limited-access.dev I receive the email, download stuff.
5. On the computer@limited-access.dev I navigate to \10.10.10.12\data and copy and replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git VCS can not be accessed without git or other source control tools.

Only git is installed on the intranet server, the server can pull/get and push/send files as the way as git does.

So for now, you can only copy and paste files as your current workflow. Or you can ask administrator of the intranet server to install [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

I like customer projects with this limitations, my head thinking bizare ideas because of this problems.

**Option A**
If you can reach the system over RDP, could it be you can manage fileshare on the maschine to mount remote folders to your local computer.
When this option is workable, than you can do normal versioning of git local without installed remote.
Sometimes hostname not work, lets try with IP. Example: `\\10.11.12.45\data` on Windows Explorer.

**Option B**
Maybe versioning software like [Fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) can help, because it don't need to be installed. But without open ports from the remote maschine to local this will not be able to sync.

Good Luck

Comment: The computer that has access over RDP doesn't have internet access except e-mail. (hilarious /s) so I end up sending data over the email in .zip to that computer.. then go to \\10.11.12.24\data and copy/replace stuff. Opening a port is near-impossible. Any more ideas?

Comment: I described my workflow in much more details. Please let me know if you have any ideas. Thank you. I'll look into Fossil though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH access to the remote machine, rsync might be helpful. It only needs to be installed on your local machine (if it's not already), and will take care of the entire synchronization process from that end.

But I agree with other answers: your best bet would be to get a Git client installed on the remote machine.